# Django and multi-image upload form

Tags: python, django

I have this form that includes around 25 inputs on the same. It includes a main image input and the rest are some text inputs or drop down menus.

The problem is that I also need the user to upload multiple images. I was thinking of doing it on the next page itself.

I have 2 questions:

- What is the best way for adding this multiple image upload form to the current form? Not related to Django, more related to the structure of the form.
- What is the best way of adding a multiple image/file to work correctly with Django? Any libraries or modules for such a job or any manual way to do it.

Comment: Formsets will let you create multiple instances of bound or unbound forms: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/forms/formsets/

Comment: Another approach: https://github.com/gterzian/django_async

Comment: @danihp The problem with async in this case is that the user might stops filling the form and exits while at the same time the images are being uploaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With **formsets** you allow the user to create several images at once. To create a formset out of an ImageForm you would do:

```
>>> from django.forms.formsets import formset_factory
>>> ImageFormSet = formset_factory(ImageForm)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/forms/formsets/

And Django comes with an optional “form wizard” application that splits forms across multiple Web pages. It maintains state in one of the backends so that the full server-side processing can be delayed until the submission of the final form.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/